# How to Insert a value multiple times in oracle database?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to Insert values multiple times like, I have PartNo and Quantity if I enter PartNo as Fibre and Qty = 3 then It should fill in 5 times as:

```
PartNo Inventory_Qty
Fibre   1
Fibre   1
Fibre   1
```

Please help me how to write a query for this.

Comment: Just execute the INSERT statement multiple times?

Comment: Something smells fishy: won't that create three duplicate rows? Do a google search for "cat food problem" OR "supermarket checkout problem" +sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In only one sql command:

```
INSERT INTO table1 ('PartNo', 'Inventory_Qty')
    SELECT 'Fibre',   1 FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Fibre',   1 FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Fibre',   1 FROM DUAL;
```

or differently (but not supported by Oracle, thanks Lukas Eder)

```
INSERT INTO table1 ('PartNo', 'Inventory_Qty')
VALUES ('Fibre',   1),
('Fibre',   1),
('Fibre',   1);
```

Comment: Be careful, ensure that ('PartNo', 'Inventory_Qty') is not the Primary key

Comment: The first syntax you mentioned is not supported by Oracle

Answer (score 3):

With a table such as

```
create table tq84_insert_test (
  partNo        varchar2(20),
  inventory_qty number(4)
);
```

you migh try

```
insert into tq84_insert_test 
select
  'Fibre', 1
from
  dual
connect by rownum <= 3;
```

Since I'm not sure if you want to insert 3 or 5 records, I assumed 3. But you might want to change the 3 in the insert statement accordingly.